# Is it bad to expose input tags in html source code?

Tags: javascript, html, web, instagram, web-deployment

I was going through page source of famous websites like twitter, instagram, snapchat etc. One thing I found common in all these websites is that there are no input tags in the page source of login/signup page. Infact there is no form tag at all. I wonder if its a security measure or something else. Can anyone answer me this?

Answer (score 0):

It is a side-effect of an overreliance of client-side programming without server-side rendering as a fallback.

It has nothing to do with security whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

In the early days of the web, all was present in the HTML code. There was little dynamic on those pages.

Through history the pages became more and more dynamic, with more JavaScript. Some document elements were created through JavaScript, in response to some user events (like adding rows to a table). This became a pattern that extended also to the initial build up of the page: some popular libraries are completely built around that idea. In the extreme, the HTML only contains one `script` tag (besides the `html` and `body` elements), and the JavaScript does the whole job of generating the page, based on some other configuration (in a database, configuration files, JSON, ...). It takes away the HTML design, and moves this responsibility to JavaScript.

This is not a security concern. Just one of the ways some frameworks work.

Answer (score 0):

The browser's page source only displays what is rendered on the server. We call this **Server Side Rendering.**

These days, with the concept of **Client Side Rendering**, most of the webpage is generated on the client side, with JavaScript frameworks like React.js. The server just generates the basic skeleton HTML.

So, to answer your question: **Why are there no input tags in the page source of login/signup page** - This is because these input tags are generated at the client-side using Javascript. This does not mitigate any security risks, as the input tags are still accessible via the DOM inspector

Answer (score -1):

It's not bad, it's just not the way those sites work. They likely use a javascript front end app and POST data to a back end API of some sort to do the login.

Input tags hark from an older variation of the web where the server prepared a page, sent it to the browser, the browser user filled in form fields, sent the data to the server as an encoded form, the server prepared a new block of html and sent ti to the browser. You'd see the page refresh with different content and huge amounts of html was flying round all the time. Some tricks were employed by browsers to make it look like a more seamless experience but there is stil lthe underlying method of working, that the whole page was replaced

The modern web tends towards single page applications; a page loads with a javascript application and the script manipulates the browser document to draw the UI, there is never again a situation where the server is wholesale shipping entire pages to the browser for display. It's all "script sends some data, probably json, to the server, gets a response and programmatically updates the local document making the browser change what it displays"

To this end somewhat the browser has become an operating system or development environment, with programming features, and access to local resources like webcams and file, and it forms a front end UI with the back end server holding and processing the data that makes the application valuable (worth purchasing or using). It's not about security, but instead about making a modern, dynamic and usable UI for a web-based application. There's no reason why they *could't* use an input tag; the javascript app running in the browser could create an input box, the user could type into it, the javascript app could pull the value out of it and send it to the server (not in a form) and get the response.. It's just that they don't need to work that way; there's a lot more freedom to get user input in various ways, send it to the server in various ways and act on the response. We are no longer tied to that older "post a form to the server" way of having dynamic content, and we haven't been tied for a long time but it's relatively more recently that really good frameworks and libraries for creating these single page apps have come along, so increasingly we see sites using them for the benefits they provide and they might bring with them ways of garnering user input without using an input tag - ways that are not subject to some limitation (probably styling) that using the tag incurs.

The modern web is mainly centred on end user experience with a more rich and fluid ui, less data being transferred for faster response times etc. All this chat between front end and back end (should) happens over HTTPS in the modern web (the CPU cost of encrypting being relatively low in these days of high powered servers and clients) so it's at least as secure as it ever was.

TLDR; input tags are less often used because they're less often needed and may bring some problems and blockers to the modern ways of developing. They aren't inherently insecure.